# How can I make my list return each element only once in a list?

Tags: python, list

So I wrote this code to return back every string in the given `lst: list` once. Here is my code

```
def make_unique(lst: list[str]):
    s = []
    for x in lst:
        if lst.count(x) == 1:
           s.append(x)
        else:
           return(x)
    return s
```

When I put in the input:

```
print(make_unique(lst=['row','mun','row']))
```

The output returns

```
row
```

but I want my output to return

```
['row','mun']
```

which is basically all the strings in the list printed once.
How can I do this??

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to do this is turn the list into a set. A set only shows each item once and thats what you want.

```py
lst=['row','mun','row']
setLst = set(lst)
for elem in setLst:
    print(elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not you try this one line short code to remove duplicates from your list and make it unique

```
def make_unique(lst):
    return list(dict.fromkeys(lst))

print(make_unique(['row','mun','row'])) #['row','mun']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set.

```
lst=['row','mun','row']
print(set(lst))
```